# Struct getting overwritten by library function

Tags: c++, arduino

I am rather befuddled by a bug where the members of a struct are sometimes being overwritten by a call to a library function that should have nothing to do with it.

After a seemingly random number of calls to Navagator::update(), the line GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()) will overwrite the navagator what object's waypoint variable points to.

The bug is pretty strange, is it possible I misplaced a pointer somewhere?

```
// TransAt.ino
// ---------------------
#include "motors.h"
#include "navagator.h"

Navagator* nav;
Waypoint w = { 43.36, -75.1 };

uint32_t timer = millis();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("MIT TransAt Vehicle Debugging");

  nav = &Navagator(&w, 1);

  Serial.print("\Setup 1 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

  Serial.print("\nSetup 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

}

void loop() 
{ 
  Serial.print("\nOuter Loop 1 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

  nav->update();

  Serial.print("\nOuter Loop 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

  //delay(100000);

  if (timer > millis()) timer = millis();

  if (millis() - timer > 2000) {
    Serial.print("\nLoop 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
    Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

    timer = millis(); // reset the timer
    nav->diagnostic();

    Serial.print("\nLoop 3 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
    Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

    int course = nav->getCourse();
    Serial.println("\nCourse: "); Serial.println(course);

    Serial.print("\nLoop 4 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
    Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);
  }

  Serial.print("\nLoop 5 Loc: "); Serial.print(nav->waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(nav->waypoints->lon);

}
```

-

```
// navagator.h
// ---------------------
#ifndef _NAVAGATOR_h
#define _NAVAGATOR_h

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>


struct Waypoint {
  double lat, lon;
};

class Navagator {
public:
  Navagator(Waypoint* w, int);
  int getCourse();  // Returns course to next waypoint (compass bearings 0-360 with 0 true North)
  void update();        // Updates navagator (Call this frequently in the main loop)
  void diagnostic();
  Waypoint* waypoints;  // Array of waypoints to pass through


private:
  int pointCount, next; // Number of waypoints, index of next waypoint
  int course;               // Last calculated course to waypoint

  bool checkWaypoint();
  void updateWaypoints();
  void startGPS();
  void updateGPS();
};


double degreesToRadians(double);
double radiansToDegrees(double);
int calculateCourse(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2);
double calculateCoordinateDistance(double, double, double, double);
double getLatitude();
double getLongitude();

#endif
```

-

```
// 
// Library for navigator guiding the TransAt vehicle
// 
// Note:    The navigator uses 0-360 compass bearings with 0 equivalent to true North and assumes 1 degree of precision 
//          All distances are measured in km
//          The course is the ideal angle between the vehicle and a waypoint
// navagator.cpp
// -------------------

#include "navagator.h"
#include <math.h>

#define EARTH_RADIUS 6371 // in km
#define WAYPOINT_RADIUS 5 // in km

#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#define GPSSerial Serial3
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&GPSSerial);

Navagator::Navagator(Waypoint* w, int count) {
  waypoints = w; 
  pointCount = count;
  next = 0;                             // start with first waypoint
  course = 90;                          // Notice that initial course is due East
  startGPS();
}

// Returns course between 0-360 degrees, where 0 is true North
int Navagator::getCourse() {
  if (!GPS.fix) // Without a fix, continue along last course.
    return course;

  // Get coordinates (In decimal degrees)
  double waypointLon = waypoints->lon;
  double waypointLat = waypoints->lat;
  double currentLon = getLongitude();
  double currentLat = getLatitude();

  Serial.print("Waypoint Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);

  // Update course
  course = calculateCourse(currentLat, currentLon, waypointLat, waypointLon);
  return course;
}

// Passed coordinates in decimal degrees
// Returns course in integer compass bearings
int  calculateCourse(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  // From https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

  // Convert to radians
  lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
  lon1 = degreesToRadians(lon1);
  lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);
  lon2 = degreesToRadians(lon2);

  double y = sin(lon2 - lon1) * cos(lat2);
  double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1);
  int course = ((int)radiansToDegrees(atan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360;                // We convert the -pi to pi result of atan2 to 360 degree compass bearings

  return course;
}

// Call this from the main loop to keep navigation up to date
void Navagator::update() {

  Serial.print("Update 1 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);

  updateGPS();

  Serial.print("Update 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);

  updateWaypoints();

  Serial.print("Update 3 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);
}

void Navagator::updateWaypoints() {
  if (checkWaypoint()) {            // If we've reached a waypoint

    if (next + 1 < pointCount)  // If there are more waypoints,
      next++;                   // Move to the next waypoint (Else, keep seeking the last waypoint)
  }
}

// Returns true if we've reached the next waypoint, else false
bool Navagator::checkWaypoint() {
  if (!GPS.fix)     // Without a fix, assume we haven't reached a waypoint
    return false;

  // Get coordinates
  double waypointLon = (waypoints + next)->lon;
  double waypointLat = (waypoints + next)->lat;
  double currentLon = getLongitude();
  double currentLat = getLatitude();

  // Return if distance between them is less than the waypoint 
  return calculateCoordinateDistance(currentLat, currentLon, waypointLat, waypointLon) < WAYPOINT_RADIUS;
}

// Takes coordinates in decimal degrees
// Returns distance between in km
double calculateCoordinateDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
  // Halversine Formula https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

  // Convert to radians
  lat1 = degreesToRadians(lat1);
  lon1 = degreesToRadians(lon1);
  lat2 = degreesToRadians(lat2);
  lon2 = degreesToRadians(lon2);

  // Find distance on unit sphere
  double a = pow(sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2), 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2), 2);   // For right triangle with sides a, b, and c
  double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

  return EARTH_RADIUS * c;
}

double degreesToRadians(double degrees) {
  return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}

double radiansToDegrees(double radians) {
  return radians * 180 / M_PI;
}

// Provides decimal degree latitude with ~1km of precision
double getLatitude() {
  double lat = GPS.latitude_fixed;

  if (GPS.lat == 'S') { // Note we're doing a character comparision here so the == is appropriate
    lat = -lat;         // Southern latitudes are negative
  }

  return lat / 10000000.0;
}

// Provides decimal degree latitude with ~1km of precision
double getLongitude() {
  double lon = GPS.longitude_fixed;

  if (GPS.lon == 'W') { // Note we're doing a character comparision here so the == is appropriate
    lon = -lon;         // Western lattitudes are negative
  }

  return lon / 10000000.0;
}

// Configures and begins reading GPS
void Navagator::startGPS() {
  GPS.begin(9600);

  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA); // Turn on RMC (recommended minimum) and GGA (fix data) including altitude
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ);        // 1 Hz update rate (In final version, these rates should be lowered and the interupt used less frequently to conserve clock cycles)
    delay(1000);

  // Create interrupt
  OCR0A = 0xAF;         // We'll use comparison register A (OCR0A) for the ATMega's ~1Hz Timer0 (When Timer0 == OCR0A == 0xAF, the interupt will fire)
  TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);    // enable compare A interrupts 
              // Note: TIMSK0 is a macro for the 'Timer Interrupt Mask Register' and OCIE0A is the bit mask specifing 'Timer/Counter Output Compare Match A Interrupt'

  // Wait for GPS to get fix
  // Actually we can't do that
  // Trying to loop here produces weird behavior where nothing is printed to Serial or we never get any data from the gps
  // Possibly try to figure out what is going on later?
}

// Interrupt is called once a millisecond, looks for any new GPS data, and stores it
SIGNAL(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  GPS.read();   // read any new GPS data (We still have to parse completed sentences in the main loop)
}

// Parses new NMEA sentences
void Navagator::updateGPS() {
  Serial.print("UpdateGPS 1 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);
  if (GPS.newNMEAreceived())
    Serial.print("**UpdateGPS 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
    Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);
    Serial.println(GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA()));

  Serial.print("UpdateGPS 3 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);
}

void Navagator::diagnostic() {

  Serial.print("\nNav 1 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);

  Serial.println("\n\nNavagation Diagnostic");
  Serial.print("Time: ");
  Serial.print(GPS.hour, DEC); Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(GPS.minute, DEC); Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(GPS.seconds, DEC); Serial.print('.');
  Serial.println(GPS.milliseconds);
  Serial.print("Date: ");
  Serial.print(GPS.day, DEC); Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(GPS.month, DEC); Serial.print("/20");
  Serial.println(GPS.year, DEC);
  Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
  Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality);
  if (GPS.fix) {
    Serial.print("Location: ");
    Serial.print(getLatitude()); Serial.print(GPS.lat); // Decimal Degrees (1/10,000,000 of a degree)
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(getLongitude()); Serial.println(GPS.lon); // Decimal Degrees (1/10,000,000 of a degree)
    Serial.print("Speed (knots): "); Serial.println(GPS.speed);
    Serial.print("Angle: "); Serial.println(GPS.angle);
    Serial.print("Altitude: "); Serial.println(GPS.altitude);
    Serial.print("Satellites: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.satellites);
  }
  Serial.print("Waypoint: "); Serial.println(next);

  Serial.print("\nNav 2 Loc: "); Serial.print(waypoints->lat);
  Serial.print(", "); Serial.println(waypoints->lon);
}
```

-

Output

...

```
0
UpdateGPS 3 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
Update 2 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
Update 3 Loc: 43.36, -75.10

Outer Loop 2 Loc: 43.36, -75.10

Loop 5 Loc: 43.36, -75.10

Outer Loop 1 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
Update 1 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
UpdateGPS 1 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
**UpdateGPS 2 Loc: 43.36, -75.10
1
UpdateGPS 3 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 2 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 3 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Outer Loop 2 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Loop 5 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Outer Loop 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
UpdateGPS 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
0.00, 0.00
1
UpdateGPS 3 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 2 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 3 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Outer Loop 2 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Loop 5 Loc: 0.00, 0.00

Outer Loop 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
Update 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
UpdateGPS 1 Loc: 0.00, 0.00
0.00, 0.00
1
```

...

Comment: `nav = &Navagator(&w, 1);` -- This does not do what you think it does.  So the question (before saying anything) -- what do you think this did?  Hint -- Temporary object.

Comment: Does it create the object in the scope of setup so that when I go to input, it is discarded? And it is just chance that parts of it are still there when I call it?

Comment: That object is created and then immediately destroyed.  Its lifetime is that statement, so you're taking the address of something that won't be around.  Also, why do you need a pointer anyway?  Just create the `Navigator` object.

Comment: Also, using `std::unique_ptr<Navigator> nav;` is what you should have used.  This allows you to create the object (now that I see that Navigator must be created with two parameters) dynamically using `std::make_unique`, and have the object clean itself up automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really clarifies things.

Comment: Regardless whether the problem is solved, a [mcve] should be provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is this line:

`nav = &Navagator(&w, 1);`

That `Navigator` object is created and then immediately destroyed.  Its lifetime is that statement, so you're taking the address of something that won't be around.  Thus the program will exhibit undefined behavior if you use `nav`, assuming it is still pointing to somewhere valid.

Since `nav` is a pointer to `Navigator`, and your current program declares this as a global variable (which has issues, but that's another story), a better approach to all of this is to use `std::unique_ptr<Navigator>`.  This will allow creation of a `Navigator` dynamically, and will auto-delete itself when the `std::unique_ptr` goes out of scope (which will be when your program terminates).

For example:

```
#include <memory>
//...
std::unique_ptr<Navigator> nav;
```

Then in your `setup()` function:

```
nav = std::make_unique<Navigator>(&w, 1);
```

Then if you want to get to the underlying `nav` pointer, use the `get()` function offered by `std::unique_ptr`:

`Navigator* ptr = nav.get();`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much.

I thought I was assigning the nav to an instance in place, but really I pointing it at a temporary object which was the source of all my travails.

I can use new to create the object in place, but I hear this isn't advisable on microcontrollers, so instead I will create the object in the global scope to avoid this issue.

Comment: You could keep most of your code now and just declare nav as `std::unique_ptr<Navigator>`.  Much better than using `new`.  I added an answer that better explains this.